# Counting in if/else java

Tags: java

Hi im trying to count in a if/else but it wont work.
Every time you try to find the number 32 it should count +1. This is not working for me..
So... i want it to count all the try's ive done to find number 32 so it shows me how much times i tried it.

Can anyone help me out?

```
String antwoord = null;
int getal = 32;
int count = 0;


if((Integer.parseInt(txt_input.getText().toString()) ) == getal)
{
    antwoord = "Goed! in: " + count + " keer";
}
else if((Integer.parseInt(txt_input.getText().toString()) ) <= getal)
{
    antwoord = "Hoger... ";
    count++;
} 
else if((Integer.parseInt(txt_input.getText().toString()) ) >= getal)
{
    antwoord = "Lager... ";
    count++;
}
count++;

lbl_hoger_lager.setText(antwoord);
```

Comment: What is the outcome of the application?

Comment: Your code around this fragment is missing. But most probably your `count` variable is just a local variable. So it’s value is lost at the end of its scope.

Comment: could you please explain more?

Comment: First you need to change your condition sign. Since ==, <= and >= will be all right for 32...

Comment: is it any reason why if number in `txt_input.getText()` is different than `getal` you counting trail twice?

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing your logic in the `if(condition).`

It should be

```
if(number is equal){
    // some operation
}
else if(number is greater){
   // some operation
}
else if(number is lesser than X ){
   // some operation
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted to do this :

```
        String antwoord = null;
        int getal = 32;
        int count = 0;

        if ((Integer.parseInt(txt_input.getText().toString())) == getal) {
            count++;
            antwoord = "Goed! in: " + count + " keer";

        } else if ((Integer.parseInt(txt_input.getText().toString())) < getal) {
            antwoord = "Hoger... ";
            // count++;
        }

        else if ((Integer.parseInt(txt_input.getText().toString())) > getal) {
            antwoord = "Lager... ";
            // count++;
        }

        lbl_hoger_lager.setText(antwoord);
```

Answer (score 1):

Some tipps:

1. You should avoid long strings of common code. For example `(Integer.parseInt(txt_input.getText().toString()) )` appears three times. It's a long, complicated expression. How about evaluating this only once and storing the result in a local variable?

   ```
   int userInput = (Integer.parseInt(txt_input.getText().toString()) );
   ```

   (and the `.toString()` is probably not necessary, too)
2. If you want to count always, count outside of the `if`.
3. `count` is a local variable. It will be `0` every time the code is executed. If you want to preserve the value from previous attempts, you must use a field.

Answer (score 0):

I just now tested with your code and it looks ok to me , obviously with some changes :

```
public class A
```

{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        String antwoord = null;
        int getal = 32;
        int count = 0;
        String k ="32";

```
    if((Integer.parseInt(k) ) == getal)
        {
            antwoord = "Goed! in: " + (count+1) + " keer";
        }
    else if((Integer.parseInt(k) ) <= getal)
        {
            antwoord = "Hoger... ";
            count++;
        }

    else if((Integer.parseInt(k) ) >= getal)
    {
            antwoord = "Lager... ";
            count++;
        }
       // count++;

        System.out.println(antwoord);
    //lbl_hoger_lager.setText(antwoord);
}
```

}

Output is :

```
Goed! in: 1 keer
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it set up, count will increment if the input is greater than or less than 32.

This should work for you:

```
String antwoord = null;
int getal = 32;
int count = 0;


if((Integer.parseInt(txt_input.getText().toString()) ) == getal)
{
    antwoord = "Goed! in: " + count + " keer";        
}
else if((Integer.parseInt(txt_input.getText().toString()) ) < getal)
{
    antwoord = "Hoger... ";    
    count++;
} 
else if((Integer.parseInt(txt_input.getText().toString()) ) > getal)
{
    antwoord = "Lager... ";    
    count++;
}

lbl_hoger_lager.setText(antwoord);
```